# Fusebox layout files not refreshing

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, railo, fusebox

I have a live site in fusebox 5.5 "production" mode.

No matter, what I do, I can not get the application to register any changes I make to a layout file. I have tried all the different fusebox reload parameters and they do work for all files, except the layout file.

For example, I delete the "parsed" folder and reload fusebox with the FB parameters in the url. I then see all the parsed files being recreated, but the layout does not refresh.

Also, if I delete the layout files and reload Fusebox, it still works without error!!!!!?? Nothing I do registers the changes to the layout files.

The only thing that works, is restarting the Railo / Coldfusion service. 
Then it picks up the changes.

Why is this happening and how do I get my application to pick up the layout changes without restarting the service??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the page being cached in the CF Administrator?  Try clearing template cache and see if that works.

Comment: I agree with this answer, Railo sometimes goes crazy and starts caching agressively even in Always mode (Settings - Performance/Caching)

Comment: Thanks - this was driving me nuts. NEVER seen anyone else mention this before so thanks for the advice. Definitely won't forget it. Worked perfectly.